# if-else statements inside if-else statements for BMI in C

Tags: c, if-statement

Can I include if-else statements inside other if-else statements? I am having to test age before BMI. IF age is less than 18 or greater than 64 program needs to not ask more questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Declare Variables
    int age;
    float height, weight, bmi;
    
    

    printf("Let's Calculate your BMI and BMI Category!\n");
    
    printf("%s", "Please enter your age: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &age);

    if (age < 18 || age > 64)
    {
        printf("BMI value is not appropriate for your age.\n");
    }


    else
    {
        printf("%s", "Please enter your height in Meters: ");
        scanf_s("%f", &height);

        printf("%s", "Please enter weight in Kilograms: ");
        scanf_s("%f", &weight);

        bmi = weight / (height * height);

        printf("Your BMI is: %f \n", bmi);

        if (bmi < 10)
        {
            printf("Your BMI category is Underweight.\n ");
        }
        else if (bmi >= 19 && bmi <= 25)
        {
            printf("Your BMI category is Ideal.\n");
        }
        else if (bmi > 25)
        {
            printf("Your BMI category is Overweight.\n");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using C . I will post my code. Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/15lqPCWpJrLdBqbQI7K6e-XPZ5ohDFQT6yOTYlqXLC2c/edit

Comment: Yes, you certainly can.  Just a note on your code, though, what happens if `bmi == 15`?

Comment: Wow! That's embarrassing. I will make that change!

Comment: You can definitely nest an if/else inside another if/else.  Beware, though, that in no time at all, it is all too easy to end up with a "bushy" tree that is almost impossible to understand, debug, or get right!  When you have more than a small handful of choices, it's generally a good idea to look for a completely different approach that can handle large numbers of cases in a parallel (not nested) way, that mere mortals can understand.  (Possibilities include switch statements, and lookup tables.)

Comment: Tip: Break this up into *functions* and make each function have a specific mission or purpose, like convert a BMI into a description. Example: `printf("Your BMI is %s.\n", bmi_label(bmi))`.

Comment: You never described the problem you have! But yes, you can have nested if-statements. BTW: Your code doesn't cover BMI in the range 10 to 18

Comment: @MaciG You should add `return 0` at the end of your code

Comment: @L-S, It's nice, but technically not required for `main`.